# XSLT remove root namespace and add namespace to another element

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have an input xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.somenamespace">
    <Child1>
        <A>a</A>
        <B>b</B>
    </Child1>
    <Child2>
        <C>c</C>
        <D>d</D>
    </Child2>
</Root>
```

I want my output xml after transformation to remove the namespace from root and add it to Element Child1 instead like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<NewRoot>
    <NewChild1 xmlns="http://www.somenamespace">
        <A>a</A>
        <B>b</B>
    </NewChild1>
    <NewChild2>
        <C>c</C>
        <D>d</D>
    </NewChild2>
</NewRoot>
```

My xslt looks like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.somenamespace"
            xmlns:test="http://www.somenamespace"
            exclude-result-prefixes="test">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <NewRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="test:Root/test:Child1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="test:Root/test:Child2"/>
    </NewRoot>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test:Root/test:Child1">
         <NewChild1> <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> </NewChild1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test:Root/test:Child2">
         <NewChild2> <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> </NewChild2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently this adds the namespace to the NewRoot element.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? This will do much more than just "move the namespace": it will transfer the entire `Child2` branch from its namespace to no-namespace.

Comment: The reason that NewRoot goes into namespace `http://www.somenamespace` is because of the `xmlns="http://www.somenamespace"` namespace declaration, which affects all literal result elements whose name is unprefixed.

Comment: michael.hor257k's comment above is apparently referring to what the OP's output example will do (by moving the default namespace declaration), not what the stylesheet will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://www.somenamespace"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <NewRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </NewRoot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:Child1">
    <NewChild1 xmlns="http://www.somenamespace">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </NewChild1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:Child2">
    <NewChild2>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="no-namespace"/>
    </NewChild2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="no-namespace">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This adds the namespace to Child1, but adds a xmlns="" to all child elements of Child1 i.e to A and B. I'd like A and B to also fall under the same namespace. How can I do that?

Comment: "*adds a xmlns="" to all child elements of Child1 i.e to A and B.*" No, it doesn't: http://xsltransform.net/bFN1yaj

Comment: @eechpeech: Are you sure you're running michael.hor's stylesheet against your original XML? It should never put A and B in no namespace. What XSLT processor are you using? I tested it using Saxon and it didn't do what you described.

Comment: @LarsH I'm using Xalan 2.7.2. I also needed to have only one child in my output i.e only B and to do that, I removed xsl:copy-of select="*". When I did this, B was preceded by xmlns="". The above solution works fine for my initial question though

Answer (score 1):

You can change it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:test="http://www.somenamespace"
            exclude-result-prefixes="test">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <NewRoot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="test:Root/test:Child1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="test:Root/test:Child2"/>
    </NewRoot>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test:Root/test:Child1">
         <test:NewChild1> <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> </test:NewChild1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test:Root/test:Child2">
         <NewChild2> <xsl:value-of select="current()"/> </NewChild2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I.e. don't declare a default namespace (`xmlns="..."`) but put NewChild1 explicitly in the `http://www.somenamespace` namespace.

This does what you asked, namely, modifies your stylesheet to "remove the namespace from root and add it to Element Child1"; but it does not produce your example output in all details (e.g. the `<A>` and `<B>` elements are still not preserved, as you didn't ask for help with that). Rather than completely rewriting your stylesheet to reproduce aspects of the example output that may not be what you intended to focus on, I'll leave it at that and let you provide feedback as to what else you specifically needed help with.

In all this, it will save time and make communication easier if you make sure you understand the difference between namespace *declarations*, namespace *prefixes*, and what *namespace* an element is in.

Comment: This does not produce the expected result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I can believe that may be true, but it would be more helpful if you state what you think the expected result is (since the question is vague on that point) or how it differs from the result of the above.

Comment: The question has the **exact** expected result - at least that's what I took the second block of code for. It's only 10 lines, so I believe you should be able to spot the differences right away. If not, I suggest you use a diff tool.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: The question has a specific *example* of the expected result ("like this"), but it doesn't appear to be the actual data the OP wants to transform, and the question does not specify all aspects of what the transformation should do in principle. **Like** in what way? Also, the OP shows signs of common confusions about namespaces, which is an additional reason that it's unsafe to take the example as a full specification.

Comment: That being said, I admit I haven't tested my code. That's why I can believe your first comment was true. I'm going to test it as soon as I have time.

Comment: I've tested my code, and it does what the OP asked: "remove the namespace from `Root` and add it to Element `Child1`". It doesn't attempt to fix other things that his existing stylesheet doesn't do. I've edited my answer to explain what this code is intended to provide.

Comment: This works fine too. Like you said, A and B are not preserved. Thanks!